# Degree of separability equals degree of separable closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

For a field $K$ of characteristic $p > 0$, and a finite field extension $L/K$, let $K_s$ be the separable closure of $K$ in $L$. I am to show that

> $[L : K]_s = [K_s : K]$.

This would mean that the number of embeddings of $L$ in an algebraic closure of $K$ (LHS) equals the number of basis vectors in $K_s$ as a vector space over $K$ (RHS). As $L/K$ is finite, every subextension of $K$ is finite, so $K_s/K$ is finite. It is also separable by construction, and is hence, for some $t ∈ ℕ$ and separable $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_t ∈ K_s$, given by 
$$K_s = K(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_t) = K(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_{t-1})(\alpha_t) = \ldots = (\ldots(K(\alpha_1))(\alpha_2) \ldots)(\alpha_t).
$$
In fact, finite separable extensions have a primitive element: $K_s = K(x)$ for some $K$-separable $x$, so yet another way to express the RHS is 
$$[K_s : K] = \deg f^x_K. 
$$

Moreover, by the separability of the $\alpha_i$, their respective minimal polynomials $f^{\alpha_i}_{K(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_{i-1})} ∈ K(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_{i-1})[X]$ have exactly as many roots as their degree, so we could write
$$ [K_s : K] = \prod\limits_{i = 1}^t \deg f^{\alpha_i}_{K(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_{i-1})}.
$$

Lastly, by the separability and finiteness of $K_s/K$, we have $[K_s : K] = [K_s : K]_s$.

You can see that I have *some* knowledge about the structure and dependencies in this world of separable extensions, but it is very much unconnected and unorganised. I feel that all ingredients should be on the table now, but that I lack a key insight that will connect all of this together.

PS: One might wonder where the characteristic of $K$ comes in, but I *think* that only pertains to the second part of the question: show that $(\exists k ∈ ℕ)([L : K]_s · p^k = [L : K])$.

Comment: Does anyone have a hint for determining $[L:K_s]$? It should be equal to some $p^k$, and we know that $[K(\alpha) : K(\alpha^{pⁿ})] = p^n$, so if we could show these are equal then we would have it, but I'm not even sure it's true..

Comment: How about this? We can write 
$[L : K_s] = \prod_{i=1}^t [K_s(α_1, α_2, ..., α_i) : K_s(α_1, α_2, ..., α_{i-1})]
                = \prod_{i=1}^t  \deg f^{α_i}_{K_s(α_1, α_2, ..., α_{i-1})}$
But all these minimal polynomials are inseparable, so of the form $g(X^{pⁿ})$, so the result follows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you seem to have some basic understanding of the material, you might be able to prove that 
$[L:K_s]_s=1$
and then use the multiplicativity of the degree of seperability to deduce that 
$$[L:K]_s=[L:K_s]_s\cdot [K_s:K]_s=[K_s:K]$$

The assumption that $K$ has positive characteristic will certainly be used in the second part of the exercise. Another nice fact: Any field of characteristic 0 is "perfect", i.e. any finite extension is seperable, so we would have nothing to show here.

Comment: I can prove, for $\alpha \in L \setminus K_s$, that $[K(\alpha):K]_s = 1$, but I'm not sure how that generalises to the whole of $L$.
And given this is true, the second part reduces to showing that $p^k ∈ \{[K_s:K], [K_s:K]_s, [L:K]_s\} = \{[K_s:K]\}$

Comment: I suppose you mean $[K(\alpha:K_s]_s]=1$?
If you have a homomorphism $\phi :L\to\overline K$, you can restrict it to a homomorphism $K(\alpha)\to \overline K$ for any $\alpha\in K$. So how many values can $\phi$ possibly take at $\alpha$?
Now for the second part of the question: No. You have to show that $[L:K_s]=p^k$.

Comment: In general the seperable degree of an extension is $\leq$ than the degree of the extension.

Comment: I did mean that. Sry. So do we have in general that for a tower $K ⊆ E ⊆ L$, we have  $[L:K]_s ≤ [E:K]_s$?

Comment: Yes, we do. You can either prove that by hand or again use that the seperable degree is multiplicative: $[L:K]_s=[L:E]_s\cdot [E:K]_s$

Comment: $\phi$ can indeed take only one value at $\alpha$ (namely $\phi|_{K(\alpha)}(\alpha)= \alpha$). But that doesn't fix $\phi$ completely on $L$, does it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108059/discussion-between-jos-van-nieuwman-and-c-putz).